# Overlay coordinates on MapView with react-native

Tags: google-maps, react-native

I am new to react-native. I am following these steps in order to create a MapView and would like to add custom images as Overlays.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-maps

There is no specific example in the Overlay component reference, but I understand it should look like:

```
<MapView
    style={{ flex: 1 }}
    initialRegion={{
      latitude: 37.78825,
      longitude: -122.4324,
      latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
      longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
    }}
  >
    <Overlay 
      image="https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg"
      bounds={[
          {latitude: 40.712216, longitude: -74.22655}, 
          {latitude: 40.773941, longitude: -74.12544}
      ]}
    />
</MapView>
```

This however fails with this error:

```
Warning: Failed prop type: Invalid prop `bounds[0]` of type `object` supplied to `MapOverlay`, expected `array`.
```

Am I passing the bounds incorrectly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have added wrong bounds data. It should be array and need to update your code as follows:

```
<Overlay 
   image="https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg"
   bounds={[
     [40.712216, -74.22655], 
     [40.773941, -74.12544]
   ]}
/>
```

Or

you need to declare two constants in your page at the top as follows:

```
const COORDINATE1 = [35.67737855391474, 139.76531982421875];
const COORDINATE2 = [35.67514743608467, 139.76806640625];
```

and your overlay code should be like this:

```
<Overlay 
  image="https://www.lib.utexas.edu/maps/historical/newark_nj_1922.jpg"
  bounds={[COORDINATE1, COORDINATE2]}
/>
```

Comment: how to overlay custom images inside <Overlay/> tag ?

I need to rotate image at certain degree and overlay that rotated imag on map.Kindly helpme at here.

Thanks